How to group by and select only the specific item in a group



test_run_id
test_id
suite_id
exe_length
message




4201
32
39
11
Hub Status does1


4201
32
39
17
Hub Status does3


4201
32
39
17
Hub Status does4


4201
32
39
18
Hub Status does7


4200
32
39
11
Hub Status does8


4197
32
39
11
Hub Status does0


4196
32
39
17
Hub Status doesn14


4196
32
39
18
Hub Status does134


4195
NULL
31
14
Hub Status does123


4187
7
12
35
Hub Status d34567


4187
7
12
35
Hub Status 345566



I have the table above,  how can I select for each matching test_run_id, the test_run_id and suite_id of the message with the minimum length?
Example:
for test_run_id=4201, test_id=32, suite_id=39, I want the message where exe_length is minimum (11). i.e message = "Hub Status does1"
when the column values are hardcoded it's easy:
select  message
    from log_message_view_uat
    where test_run_id= 4201 and test_id=32 and suite_id=39 and exe_length = (select min(exe_length) from log_message_view_uat
    where test_run_id= 4201 and test_id=32 and suite_id=39)

How can I get the same message per column parameter in the database?

Use the row_number() windows function. Search SO for the getting the top1 per group.

But what do you want for run_id 4187? They have same length.

Distinct on does exactly that: demo
select distinct on (1,2,3) *
from log_message_view_uat
order by 1,2,3,exe_length;




test_run_id
test_id
suite_id
exe_length
message




4187
7
12
35
Hub Status 345566


4195
null
31
14
Hub Status does123


4196
32
39
17
Hub Status doesn14


4197
32
39
11
Hub Status does0


4200
32
39
11
Hub Status does8


4201
32
39
11
Hub Status does1



1,2,3 are column numbers, which means for each combination of test_run_id, test_id and suite_id you get one row, and it will be the first one in the order of exe_length, ascending.
If you only want the message, you'll need explicit column names:
select distinct on(test_run_id,test_id,suite_id)message
from log_message_view_uat
order by test_run_id,test_id,suite_id,exe_length;


excellent this is what i wanted

If the above answer (or any following) resolved your issue, or lead you to the solution, then kindly accept it. This aids future users having the same or similar issue and removes it from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered.

You can do it without an inner select with first_value
    select 
        test_run_id,
        test_id,
        suite_id, 
        exe_length,
        message,
        first_value(message) over (partition by test_run_id, test_run_id, suite_id order by exe_length) as min_len
    from log_message_view_uat
    order by test_run_id desc

The relevant function is:
first_value(message) -- we want the first value of a group of values
  over (
      partition by test_run_id, test_run_id, suite_id -- this works basically like a group by for the function without combining all the rows into one.
      order by exe_length -- in order for first_value to make any sense we better define an order.
) as min_len

For more information about first_value
See the DB-Fiddle

Use row_number windows function if wanting just one per group (even if ties). If you want to keep the ties, then use dense_rank.
--if wanting just one even if ties
select 
 test_run_id, 
 test_id, 
 suite_id, 
 exe_length, 
 message
from (
    select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by test_run_id, test_id, suite_id order by exe_length) as rn
    from log_message_view_uat
    )z
where rn = 1
order by 1




test_run_id
test_id
suite_id
exe_length
message




4187
7
12
35
Hub Status 345566


4195
null
31
14
Hub Status does123


4196
32
39
17
Hub Status doesn14


4197
32
39
11
Hub Status does0


4200
32
39
11
Hub Status does8


4201
32
39
11
Hub Status does1



--if wanting ties
select 
 test_run_id, 
 test_id, 
 suite_id, 
 exe_length, 
 message
from (
    select *, 
      dense_rank() over (partition by test_run_id, test_id, suite_id order by exe_length) as rn
    from log_message_view_uat
    )z
where rn = 1
order by 1




test_run_id
test_id
suite_id
exe_length
message




4187
7
12
35
Hub Status 345566


4187
7
12
35
Hub Status d34567


4195
null
31
14
Hub Status does123


4196
32
39
17
Hub Status doesn14


4197
32
39
11
Hub Status does0


4200
32
39
11
Hub Status does8


4201
32
39
11
Hub Status does1



fiddle

try using GROUP BY and HAVING
select  message
from log_message_view_uat
where test_run_id= 4201 and test_id=32 and suite_id=39 
GROUP BY test_run_id
HAVING exe_length = MIN(exe_length);

